# How do I turn off thumbnails in the file manager?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

For privacy reasons I'd like to clean out the hidden folder `~/.thumbnails`, how do I manage the information in this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [dconf-tools [image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools), then launch the `dconf-editor`

And then navigate to:

`org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache`

[image]

From there you can set the number of days the system will keep thumbnails around.

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same via the command line by running this command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-age 180`

replacing *180* with the desired amount of days.